# executing a function within an array within a hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a Perl data structurte like so

```
%myhash = (
  k1 => v1, 
  kArray => [
    {
      name => "anonymous hash",
      ...
    },
    \&funcThatReturnsHash,
    {
      name => "another anonymous hash",
      ...
    }
  ]
);
```

Elsewhere I iterate through the list in `kArray` which contains a bunch of  hashes. I would like to either process the actual hash  OR the hash *returned* by the function.

```
foreach my $elem( @{myhash{kArray}} ) {

  if (ref($elem) == "CODE") {
     %thisHash = &$elem;
  }
  else {
     %thisHash = %$elem;
  }
  ...
}
```

However `ref ($elem)` is always scalar or undefined. I tried `func`, `&func`, `\&func`, `\%{&func}`, in `%myhash` to no effect.

how do I extract the hash within the function in the main body?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the code sample you give being invalid Perl, the main problems seem to be that you are using `==` to compare strings instead of `eq`, and you are assigning a hash *reference* to a hash variable `%thishash`. I assure you that `ref $elem` never returns `SCALAR` with the data you show

It would help you enormously if you followed the common advice to `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your code

This will work for you

```
for my $elem ( @{ $myhash{kArray} } ) {

    my $this_hash;

    if ( ref $elem eq 'CODE' ) {
         $this_hash = $elem->();
    }
    else {
         $this_hash = $elem;
    }

    # Do stuff with $this_hash
}
```

or you could just use a `map` like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dump;

my %myhash = (
    k1     => v1,
    kArray => [
        {
            name => "anonymous hash",
        },
        \&funcThatReturnsHash,
        {
            name => "another anonymous hash",
        }
    ]
);

for my $hash ( map { ref eq 'CODE' ? $_->() : $_ } @{ $myhash{kArray} } ) {
  say $hash->{name};
}


sub funcThatReturnsHash {
    {  name => 'a third anonymous hash' };
}
```

#### output

```
anonymous hash
a third anonymous hash
another anonymous hash
```

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on strict and warnings, you'll see that:

```
foreach my $elem(@{mynahs{kArray}}) {
```

Isn't valid. You need at the very least a `$` before `mynahs`.

But given something like this - your approach works - here's an example using `map` to 'run' the code references:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub gimme_hash {
    return { 'fish' => 'paste' };
}

my $stuff =
    [ { 'anon1' => 'value' }, 
      \&gimme_hash, 
      { 'anon2' => 'anothervalue' }, ];

my $newstuff = [ map { ref $_ eq "CODE" ? $_->() : $_ } @$stuff ];
print Dumper $newstuff;
```

Turns that hash into:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'anon1' => 'value'
          },
          {
            'fish' => 'paste'
          },
          {
            'anon2' => 'anothervalue'
          }
        ];
```

But your approach does work:

```
foreach my $element ( @$stuff ) {
   my %myhash;
   if ( ref $element eq "CODE" ) {
      %myhash = %{$element -> ()}; 
   }
   else {
      %myhash = %$element;
   }
   print Dumper \%myhash; 
}
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'anon1' => 'value'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'fish' => 'paste'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'anon2' => 'anothervalue'
        };
```